# Numerically minimize a function

Tags: numerical-optimization

[question screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grZtl.png)

I am very bad at maths in general, so I dont even know which topic this question falls into.
Got this from a mathemtatics exam, and I would like to know where can I get some example solutions related to this question. I personally can learn maths more by observing example solutions rather than the theories.
Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Isn't that a vector-valued function?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know that either.

Comment: Well, you could write your question in MathJax instead of providing a screen-shot.  You could also mention the source of the problem.